# ¿ Mover un objeto con onMouseDrag en Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Este código en teoría funciona para mover un objeto según he visto en tutoriales, pero a mi no se me mueve la esfera y no sé por qué. Le he asignado el script y todo pero nada... qué falla?

```
public class mouseDrag : MonoBehaviour {

float distance = 10;

void onMouseDrag() {

    Vector3 mousePosition = new Vector3 (Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, distance);
    Vector3 objPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (mousePosition);

    transform.position = objPosition;

}


// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Su codigo tiene un error de typo no es `onMouseDrag()` es `OnMouseDrag()` la o es en mayusculas:

```
  float distance = 10;

void onMouseDrag() {

    Vector3 mousePosition = new Vector3 (Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, distance);
    Vector3 objPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (mousePosition);

    transform.position = objPosition;

}
```

.

```
void OnMouseDrag() {
//..
```

---

con lo anterior le deberia de funcionar si no es asi pruebe el codigo siguiente es mas menos igual que el suyo, pero ademas este tiene que hacer cambiar el color del objeto si este tampoco le funciona creo que el error es por cosa de Trigger.

```
//..
public Renderer rend;

void Start () {

    rend = GetComponent<Renderer>();
}

//..
float distance = 10;
Vector3 mousePosition; 

/*El vector esta fuera para que no tenga que 
  ser creado cada ves, no es muy bueno que digamos 
  crear cientos de objetos una y otra ves, si no es 
  necesarios, asi no emplear ese tiempo en crearlos y 
  hacer trabajar de mas al recolector de basura.*/

  //P.D: con el tipo vector no es muy apreciable 
  //(por no entrar en tecnicismos) 
  //hasta cierto punto, pero
  //pienso que es mejor acostumbrase a no crear objetos en lugares que se 
  //llaman "x" veces por frame. 

void OnMouseDrag() {

    mousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
    mousePosition.z = distance;
    transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (mousePosition);

    rend.material.color -= Color.white * Time.deltaTime;
}
//..
```

Comment: @RfMvs vi su comentario en otra respuesta que le deje, diciendo algo *...que no le funcionaba...* si con el codigo que le dejo no le funciona es posible que las dos no le funcionen por lo mismo, si es asi comentemelo y lo intentamos solucionar, yo tengo una idea de donde puede estar su problema pero no quiero liarme a mostrarle como solucionarlo pues me falta saber primero si le funciona el codigo como yo de dije. Saludos